# Spring data couchbase return null on one field

Tags: spring, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I want to do a simple getAll, but I have a null value on an embedded object.
Response :

```
[
  {
    "id": "0da716f2-6ef0-404f-9403-4d869a6b6853",
    "channelName": "general",
    "broadcast": {
      "tenantId": "45bd5d1f-f585-44df-b37c-7882c123a492",
      "broadcastName": "fix",
      "id": null
    }
  }
]
```

I cant get the broadcastId, in couchbase web I can see that its present there but I cannot get it when using getAll() nor any other method.
Classes :

```
@Document
//lombok...
public class Broadcast  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
    //@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    //@Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
    private String id;
    
    @Field
    private String tenantId;
    
    @Field
    private String broadcastName;
    }


@Document
//lombok...
public class Channel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
    private String id;
    
    @Field
    private String channelName;
    
    @Field
    private Broadcast broadcast;
}
```